# Permission error with pip Python 3

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, terminal, pip

I am using Python 3 on Mac OS X. Everything was perfect, I used to install packages like this:

```
pip install somePackage
```

But IDLE stopped working so I had to re-install it. After that, when I ran pip, I got `pip is not defined` so I had to install pip. Now, every time I try to install a package using pip, I get this error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 377, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, dest, False, fixer=fixer, filter=filter)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 287, in clobber
    ensure_dir(dest)  # common for the 'include' path
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pygame'
```

I thought it may be from the version so I updated it. Now, whenever I run `pip install something` I get this error:

> Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/bc/hwpn9sqn5352xcbst0p89snm0000gn/T/pip-build-hSNyxK/termcolor/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/bc/hwpn9sqn5352xcbst0p89snm0000gn/T/pip-U3ZtNq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/bc/hwpn9sqn5352xcbst0p89snm0000gn/T/pip-build-hSNyxK/termcolor/

I can't even delete a package - when I run `pip uninstall something` I get this error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/uninstall.py", line 76, in run
    requirement_set.uninstall(auto_confirm=options.yes)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 346, in uninstall
    req.uninstall(auto_confirm=auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/bc/hwpn9sqn5352xcbst0p89snm0000gn/T/pip-OQKY_a-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

My pip version is :

```
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

I am using Mac 10.12.6

How can I fix this?

Comment: execute as sudo

Comment: Sudo pip somepackage?

Comment: Can you include the output of `$ which python` from the command line, and `>>> import site; site.getsitepackages()` from Python? Also, please mention what distribution of Python you're using (system version, Python.org version, Homebrew version, Anaconda, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permission error you're seeing is due to the fact that your `site-packages` directory (where pip is trying to install to) is protected and owned by an administrator.

#### Where is the site packages directory

It depends on your Python distribution. That's why I asked for you to include the output of the `$ which python` command (from the command line), and the `>>> import site; site.getsitepackages()` command (from Python). These will help you figure out where your site packages directory is. Also, running `pip -v` will print the directory to which pip is trying to install.

It is important to note that Macs come with a system version of Python. You should not install any packages accessible to this system version of Python, because it is used by the system and you can potentially interfere with its normal workings and/or install malicious versions of packages that will do bad things when the system uses that Python (e.g., if someone made a nasty egg and called it "os" and put it in the site-packages directory for your system Python, then the next time the system python version ran "import os" it would import the nasty egg.)

#### Why overriding with `sudo pip install` is not a good solution

While running your `pip install` command as sudo would *probably* solve the problem, this is a short-term fix that is *very bad* for the reasons mentioned in my comment in @Nenand's answer - running `pip install X` downloads the egg for X from the internet, and runs `python setup.py build && python setup.py install` on whatever happens to be in the `setup.py`. While it's easy to be lulled into complacency because, hey, it works!, it's also naive to **trust strangers on the internet** (and let's face it, the people who make pip packages *are* strangers to you).

***EDIT:*** I didn't even think of this, but there is also the potential that you mis-type a library, or guess the wrong name, and end up with one you REALLY didn't want (typosquatting). See [this BleepingComputer](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/ten-malicious-libraries-found-on-pypi-python-package-index/) article on typosquatting pip packages.

#### The proper solution

The proper solution is to figure out *why* your `site-packages` directory is protected, and either fix its permissions, or change the `site-packages` directory pip is using.

<s>I suspect</s> the reason you're seeing this permissions error is that pip is trying to install to the system Python's `site-packages` directory, which is owned by root for a good reason. The system Python is located at `/usr/bin/` and its `site-packages` directory is located at the following directories:

```
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/site-python'
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages'
```

My advice, in this case, is to install Python using Homebrew, Python.org, or Canopy, which will keep your snakes in separate cages and will leave the system Python alone. On my system, `python` is the system python, `python2` is Python version 2, and `python3` is Python version 3. This also makes it more clear which version I'm using. I also do not have a `pip` command - not on my path - so I can't accidentally install something to my system Python. I have to explicitly call `pip2` or `pip3`. Using Homebrew Python will do all of this for you, so that's my most-favored recommendation of the many Python distributions available.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate that. I installed Python from python.org. 
How can I do like you? should I just uninstall all python versions and pip then reinstall it using Homebrew? One more thing, would virtual environment fix this and do something as you have or that is for something else?

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned virtual environments, as I forgot to mention those in my answer. The virtualenv package was invented to avoid this kind of tangle of Pythons and libraries. However, you still have to install the virtualenv package somewhere, and if you are using your system Python, it isn't optimal (the system version of Python is going to be older, since it was bundled with your computer). So use virtualenv after you've chosen your Python distro and gotten that sorted out.

Comment: As far as which distro to use, if you don't have a specific reason to stick with Python.org's Python, I would recommend a switch to Homebrew (it has nice integration with other packages mixing C++/Python, like TensorFlow and Numpy, and can also manage its own environmental variables for each separate version of Python, so you don't end up in the hell of having mixed-up $PYTHONPATH locations and incompatible modules). But you can (in *theory*) accomplish the same clean separation of multiple versions with any distro through careful .bash_profile editing and consistent usage of virtualenv.