# Pip doesn't work (Mac)

Tags: python, macos, selenium, pip, python-3.6

I am using python 3.6 and I have MAC OS X 10.12.6. I want to install packages like selenium and django. When I type pip install selenium it gives me this error

OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/selenium'

Does anyone know why this is happening? I am in the same directory as pip is installed.

Comment: The Error is about Selenium not pip! Seems Selenium is already installed, and the OS is telling you about some permission errors in running it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission error with pip Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46675670/permission-error-with-pip-python-3)

Answer (score 3):

This error shows when you are trying to overwrite macOS inbuilt Python packages, which is protected by macOS's System Integrity Protection (SIP).

Since you are using Python 3 (which should be installed manually by you.), you should use `pip3`, like so:

```
pip3 install selenium
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems as though the user you're using doesn't have permissions to write to that directory. Instead of installing it system-wide, you could install the package for your own user:

```
$ pip install --user selenium
```