# pip install tweepy error

Tags: python, macos, pip, tweepy

When I try to install tweepy using pip (pip install tweepy) I get the below error on my mac (10.12.3). Please help.

`OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/s0/0j_bp8b96bl2mzltwxnc56300000gn/T/pip-9zf_EM-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info`

Comment: It seems that you need do `sudo pip install tweepy` (would ask your password), in terminal. This would temporarily make you superuser (with hopefully sufficient rights).

Comment: You can use `sudo` to get around the permissions problem, but I would recommend using a [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) instead, which doesn't require pip packages be installed globally into system folders.

Comment: Have tried using with sudo and facing the same issue. :(  I haven't used virtual environment before let me check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission error with pip Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46675670/permission-error-with-pip-python-3)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given the program permissions to edit this. You probably have to be the administrator to do it, or run the program as an administrator. It fails because it doesn't have permissions. Putting `sudo` before the command might work.

Comment: Have tried using with sudo and facing the same issue. :(

Comment: @Holmes Are you on the administrator account? Do you get the same error when trying to install other packages?

Comment: Yes using admin account. Not for all packages. However when run "pip install --upgrade six scrape" I get the same issue. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your response! It looks like an issue with pip. Have successfully install using sudo pip install tweepy --user.

source: http://marcelog.github.io/articles/mac_osx_python_pip_install_operation_not_permitted.html

Comment: If this is the correct answer, it should be accepted.